# How to response with file stream and json object as single response of web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Web API, 
My current web API is responding JSON object with 2 properties as below.
I'd: 1, FieldName:somename

Now, need to include one FILE (.CERT) in response along with existing JSON properties.

How to accomplish this ?

[Authorize]

```
[Route("getfileAndProperties")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTestFile()
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/timetable.cer");

   var p = new Person() {Id=1,userField="name"};
//need to include this Person object into response along with file.
    if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
    {
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
    }
    else
    {
        // Serve the file to the client
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "SampleImg";                
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @Div Added comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using Base64String conversion of file and include into JSON response.

Thanks